# mysql2/promise require database connection file

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise

I have only been working with PHP before going to Node.JS. What I was able to do in PHP when working with MYSQL was that I could include the database.php file in the files I wanted to execure queries in.

It doesn't seem to be the same in Node.Js. This is my database.js file

```
const mysql  = require("mysql2/promise");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'XXXX',
    database: 'nodelogin'
});

module.exports = db;
```

Then I require this in my file login.js

```
const db  = require("../../database");
```

However, when I then try to run `db.query(sql, [variable])` I get **db.query is not a function**.

Why is this? It shouldn't be that more complicated or should it?

Comment: you need to await the `await mysql.createConnection`.. `db` will be a Promise at that point and won't contain the methods.. rtm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper

Comment: plug: I just use this https://github.com/lcherone/autorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [connection pool](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools) instead, you can include the pool once, then call query on it, like so:

**db-config.js**

```
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

console.log("Creating connection pool...")
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    database: 'test_db',
    password: 'password'
})

module.exports = pool;
```

**test.js**

```
// Require to whereever db-config is 
const pool = require('./db-config.js');

async function testQuery() {
    const results = await pool.query("select * from users");
    console.table(results[0]);
}

testQuery();
```

Comment: doing it this way, require is cached, but on multiple places like inside express handlers will quickly hammer connections, anti-pattern

Comment: but this means I have to include "database.js" in every query I make? Isn't there a way to just include it once in each file?

Comment: Good point @LawrenceCherone, I've updated the answer.